# unable to import UnicodeWriter python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, unicode, dictionary

I am trying to write a dictionary containing values with unicode characters to a text file and was thinking of using UnicodeWriter as mentioned in the python csv documentation. But I am unable to import it as the module is not recognized by python. I was wondering whether this is a problem with my version of python? Also if it is not possible to do it this way, is there any way to specify encoding while using the dictWriter class in python.

Comment: It is hard to tell what have been asked here

Answer (score 3):

`UnicodeWriter` isn't an actual module in any version of Python. The code given in the documentation is an example which you'll have to copy into your own project.

Comment: oh that makes sense actually! Thanks. I think I was mislead by a couple of questions on so which had the statements like: from UnicodeWriter import UnicodeWriter. Thanks.

Comment: For future reference: link to the mentioned documentation example: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples